# How to sort a `list` finder query? Results are not showing up in the defined order

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

The countries are not showing up in ascending order.

```php
$coutryTable = TableRegistry::get('Country');
$getall = $coutryTable
    ->find('list', [
        'keyField' => 'phonecode',
        'valueField' => function ($row) {
            return $row['name'] . ' (+ ' . $row['phonecode'] . ')';
        }
    ])
    ->order([
        'Country.name' => 'ASC'
    ]);
```

Comment: Check the generated SQL, the query builder looks correct. Also show what your results look like _exactly_, ie how exactly _are_ they sorted, if not ascending by name? And what _exactly_ do you expect the results to look like instead?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$coutryTable = TableRegistry::get('Country');

```
    $getall = $coutryTable->find('list', ['keyField' => function ($rows) {
        return $rows['name'] . ' (+ ' . $rows['phonecode'] . ')';
    }, 'valueField' => function ($row) {
        return $row['name'] . ' (+ ' . $row['phonecode'] . ')';
    }])->order(['Country.id' => 'ASC']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try asort function https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_asort.asp

```
$coutryTable = TableRegistry::get('Country');
//pr($coutryTable);die();
$getall = $coutryTable->find('list', ['keyField' => 'phonecode', 'valueField' => function ($row) {
            return $row['name'] . ' (+ ' . $row['phonecode'] . ')';
        }])
->toArray();

asort($getAll);

print_r($getAll);
```